Customizing WooCommerce checkout fields using actions and filters
So my problem is with adding a custom checkout field in WooCommerce cheout page.
I have gone through https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/customizing-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ which essentially gives everything I should know to work this but for some reason everything I try, whether removing some fields or adding new custom fields nothing works.
And on debugging it seems the woo-commerce hooks do not fire at all. I am lost on what I am missing. Note that I am using latest WordPress and woo-commerce and I am trying this on a blank/ fresh site with 2024 theme(I have tried others like storefront as well), hence there should be nothing blocking woocommerce hooks from firing.
Also note this code should finally end in a custom plugin hence using other plugins will be counter-productive.
This is my code but it is not working:
     /**
      * Add the field to the checkout
     */
     add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

     function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

         echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . esc_html__( 'My Field' ) . '</h2>';

         woocommerce_form_field(
             'my_field_name',
              array(
                  'type'        => 'text',
                  'class'       => array( 'my-field-class form-row-wide' ),
                  'label'       => __( 'Fill in this field' ),
                  'placeholder' => __( 'Enter something' ),
              ),
              $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' )
         );

         echo '</div>';

      }


First try to clear the browser cache, second, remove the product from the cart and add the product again in the cart. If both the above points don't work, create a new page and try this shortcode in Classic Editor [woocommerce_checkout]

This is certainly because you need to switch back to Classic Checkout instead of currently using the new Checkout Block, that only allow very few customizations.

Ah this is exactly what I was missing, classic checkout, unfortunately since this code is to be used in a plugin I don't see a viable way of adding checkout fields which should work with both classic and blocks. But in the very least I do know where the issue lies. Thanks a bunch!
